# Is it normal to call two activities from two buttons in sequence

Tags: android, button, android-activity, start-activity

I didn't know how to phrase the question properly so let me explain.
I have noticed that on the android platform that when you press two buttons in one activity in quick sequence (press one button then the other before the activity has a chance to leave the screen) that two activities are called one after another. It is not visible while it happens but if you press the back button then the activity that was called with the second button leaves (finishes) and the activity that was called with the first button shows up. You have to go back again to go back to the calling Activity. So you have to press back twice to get to Activity 2's parent activity.

So I want to know if this is a problem for others and if so how would you go about fixing that. Or do you think this is not much of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to pass this problem. I have a base activity class that every other activity in my application inherits from. I override

onResume with:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    setCanStartNewActivity(true);
}
```

and startActivityForResult with:

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)
{
    //Does not allow starting a new activity unless previous activity returned
    //This is a trick to stop multiple simultaneous button presses starting multiple 
    //activities simultaneously.
    if(!canStartNewActivity)
        return;
    setCanStartNewActivity(false);
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

This basically makes sure only one new activity can be started for a button press. If you let go of two buttons at the same time only the button released the earliest (even by 10 microseconds) will be fired and the other will still send the intent but it will not fire until the first fired activity returns or the app dies.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` after `startActivity(your_intent);` that way the activity you are leaving finishes and you get to the next one, so you dont have to press back twice to get to it's parent Activity.

Comment: Sorry you might have misunderstood what I was trying to say. I have a home activity with 2 buttons. I click button 1 and then really quickly I click button 2 all on home activity. Then it shows the activity for button 2. When I press back i go to the activity called with button 1. So the second called activity was not called from the first called activity but both were called from home at the same time.

Comment: Activities are kept in a stack. So the back button will actually pop the last one which is the Activity called from the first Button.

Comment: Yes I know, so i guess my question is, is this something really bad. Will it turn off the user from the app if they quickly click 2 buttons and the back button doesn't do what they expect it to do.

Comment: What do you want the back  button to do if you click two buttons on a row?

Comment: I am writing a children's app for my employer, and children like to just mash fingers everywhere, so this is just a off the wall question, not extremely important except for when my boss sees something like that and wants it gone. I have never heard of it being a problem but I decided to pose this question anyway.

Comment: Yes but you didnt really answer! What do you want to do after the 2 buttons are clicked in row? Do you want to return to parent or to the first button clicked Activity ?

Comment: Return to parent activity. I would use startActivity(parentActivyNameIntent) but I dont wanna add another new activity on top of the stack, and the different technologies I am using for this app make the transition time between starting a new home activity too long (it makes you think the app has frozen with a black screen). FYI I am using vuforia augmented reality plugin for Unity3D and adding layouts with regular Java.

Comment: Then just add finish() after startActivity() and override the onBackKeyPressed() to finish the Activity too. You have to do it for both buttons and Activities though if you want to "catch" every possible combination of the buttons pressed!!

Comment: If I add finish() after startActivity() then when i press back i will go back the home activity will no longer be there and i will exit the application.

Comment: Try to add moveTaskToBack(true) on the onPause() of both Activities and see if it helps!